# Proteger código ajax sem Sessão

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Olá. Estou com dificuldades para saber como fazer pra proteger um código ajax na minha página. Eu tenho um cadastro PHP com um formulário e tenho um campo criar um nome de usuário. Mas quando o usuário sai do campo eu verifico através de um código ajax se o usuário já existe. Mas o código ajax fica exposto no console do navegador pra página que faz a verificação. Tem como ocultar esse ajax ou contornar isso de alguma forma?

```
$("#usuario").blur(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'verifica_usuario.php',
      data: {
       nome:name,
      },
      success: function (response) {
          if($("#usuario").val()==""){
              $('#name_status').html("");
              $("#usuario").css("background-color","#ffffff");
              $("#enviar").attr("disabled",false);
          }else if(response=="true"){
              $('#name_status').html("Já existe esse usuário cadastrado");
              $("#usuario").css("background-color","#F6CECE");
              $("#enviar").attr("disabled",true);
          }else if(response=="false"){
              $( '#name_status' ).html("Usuário válido");
              $("#usuario").css("background-color","#CEF6D8");
              $("#enviar").attr("disabled",false);
          }
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Como assim ocultar?

Comment: Ocultar para que o usuário entre no console do navegador e não veja esse código fonte acima, pois ele fica vinculado a minha página

Comment: Não dá para você ocultar, poderia minificar o código, mas acho que só.

Comment: front-end vc nao oculta vc deve proteger seu sistema a nivel de backend.

Comment: e como eu faria isso?

Comment: Não consigo ocultar a requisição Ajax, mas fiz uma verificação no código php que busca o usuário. Se alguém tentar acessar o arquivo diretamente pela url eu redireciono ele. Por enquanto acho que vai servir.